# Python tests for membership limitations?

Tags: python

I have a problem with a method I use to test for membership in a geography list and remove entries from a list of budgets that fail this check. What is interesting is that this method needs to be run 3 times before it catches 100% of the failing entries.

**budg element Examples:**

```
budg = ['KELOG_PSOD_32773                                  20131125 000327   73144652.3376898.6 9769.50', 'KELOG_PSOD_32774                                  20131125 000327   74140034.3406629.9 4473.90']
```

**geo element Examples:**

```
geolist = ['KELOG_GEO_32773','KELOG_GEO_32775']

def remove_entry(budg, geolist):
    for e in budg:
        record = 'KELOG_GEO_' + e[11:e.index(' ')]
        if record not in geolist:
            print e
            removed.append(budg.pop(budg.index(e)))
```

I am running this against lists that are about 2500 entries each. As of today 44 failing entries exist in the budg list. Consistently there are always 7 false positives in the budg list after running this method once. Then 4 of them are caught running it a second time. Finally the remaining 3 are found on the third run. I know I can just run the method 3 times in my script and call it a day, but this has really begun to bug me.

I tried to reverse sort the list, and interesting enough I pull 37 of 44 failing entries on the first try, but some of them are entries that would be in the second, and third run results if I do not reverse sort the list.

Are any you aware of any limitations to membership tests that I could be violating with this code? Have any of you seen behavior with lists like this before?

Answer (score 7):

You are removing elements from `budg` *while looping over it*. The `for` loop iterator does not update its index when you do that:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in lst:
...     print i
...     lst.remove(i)
... 
1
3
```

Here `2` was skipped because the iterator first processed `lst[0]`, then moved to `lst[1]` which by that time was from a list with `[2, 3]` in it, not `[1, 2, 3]`.

Use a `while` loop instead:

```
i = 0
while i < len(budg):
    e = budg[i]
    record = 'KELOG_GEO_' + e.split(None, 1)[0][11:]
    if record not in geolist:
        removed.append(budg.pop(i))
    else:
        i += 1
```

Now you control directly what index you are processing, and only increment `i` when *not* removing an element.

Comment: You could also use `for i in xrange(len(budg)-1, -1, -1):` to step over the list backwards, then you don't have to have a special handler to conditionally modify the counter.

Comment: @SilasRay: sure, but then you'd have to reverse `removed` as well, or insert at the start.

Comment: True enough.  Guess it boils down to whether `removed` is going to be long compared to `budg` as to which is best.

Answer (score 1):

You should not remove an element from a list while iterating over it. The reason is that this modifies the indices of the elements to remove and that, in turn, changes where the loop will continue its iteration.

You should figure out which elements to remove first and then remove them after that.

Comment: Or step backwards through the list instead of forwards; then you can do it in one pass instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're changing the list you're iterating over. There's more than one way to doing avoid that. One easy to understand and fast way is to just create a new list and leave out the items you want removed, then replace the original list with that afterwards. Here's what I mean:

```
budg = ['KELOG_PSOD_32773                                  20131125 000327   73144652.3376898.6 9769.50',
        'KELOG_PSOD_32774                                  20131125 000327   74140034.3406629.9 4473.90']

geoset = {'KELOG_GEO_32773', 'KELOG_GEO_32775'}  # note this is now a set

def remove_entry(budg, geoset):
    cleaned = []
    for e in budg:
        record = 'KELOG_GEO_' + e[11:e.index(' ')]
        if record in geoset:  # keep it
            cleaned.append(e)
    budg[:] = cleaned

remove_entry(budg, geolist)
print 'budg:', budg
```

Another nice thing about this approach is that it can be reduced to one line of code:

```
budg = [e for e in budg if 'KELOG_GEO_' + e[11:e.index(' ')] in geoset]
```

As noted in a comment in near the beginning of the revised code, I changed `geolist` into `geoset` because testing for membership in a `set` is generally much faster than checking for it in a list if the list is large.